# Fixing a question about finding specific hardware

Tags: discussion

My question [replacement rgb led strips for asus aura sync?](https://superuser.com/questions/1357346/replacement-rgb-led-strips-for-asus-aura-sync) was closed as off topic:

"Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits your needs."

How do I phrase the question about the hardware I am looking for without it being about shopping? My end goal is to find a less expensive version of the manufacturers hardware that is still compatible - and I feel confident it can be phrased to help future users as well.

Comment: My reading of the question is that you're sorting out purchase options.  What you want to know is off-topic.  It might be better just to discuss it on Root Access.

Comment: Or you could ask on our sister site [hardwarerecs.se].

Comment: @fixer1234, that is kind of the end goal, but to get there I am trying to figure out exactly what I am looking for that can be considered a replacement. Or is that still off topic?

Comment: @gparyani, thank you I will check that out. Is there a way to get my question moved there?

Comment: @fixer1234, i can't find an adapter between the LED and the motherboard, is figuring that out off topic as well?

Comment: @Jordan.J.D - Yes, your original question was already migrated to hardware recommendations by the way

Comment: @Ramhound I flagged it and asked for migration. Thanks! I’ll be posting a few questions there then.

Comment: I didn’t say the question about an adapter would be within scope at hardware recommendations.  Your original question, which you asked for a migration, was in fact migrated

Comment: @Ramhound sorry I took your answer as a combination of my questions. Where should my adapter question go?

Comment: If your asking for a recommendation of which adapter might work, then hardware recommendation might work, read the help center or ask on meta hardware recommendations